# Ajax hello world module not fount error

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I trying to use this module [LINK](https://github.com/metalbox/Ajax-Search-Joomla-Module) for learning purpose, but when make the ajax request the response is a error message "Not Found"

Somebody say: Routing should change in j3.6

But the only external file to the included module is this and I think the route is fine.

```
include_once JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';
```

Why can not you find the path to the file?

Or

What file does it need to work?

Comment: If you are using Joomla 3.6 than obviously you didnt check whats written at the bottom of that link `Does not work in joomla >= 3.6`.

Comment: That is my version in github for this topic in stackoverflow O.o , created to try to make it work in joomla 3.6 and that anyone can use it if it works, I tried and I could not.

Comment: I am sorry but I think your english was a bit difficult to understand. Anyways if time permits, I will check your module and let you know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your module, and found a silly mistake made by you. its not about route file. Problem lies in your renaming the module to mod_jd_arq. Previous module name was mod_ajax_search, therefore it was written as

```
 request = {
                    'option' : 'com_ajax',
                    'module' : 'ajax_search',
                    'data'   : value,
                    'format' : 'raw'
                };
```

You need to change this to

```
request = {
                    'option' : 'com_ajax',
                    'module' : 'jd_arq',
                    'data'   : value,
                    'format' : 'raw'
                };
```

in your mod_jd_arq.php file.

Also in place of

```
var value   = $('input[name=data]').val(),
```

in the same file on line 13. You can change it to

```
var value   = $('input[name="data"]').val(),
```

Comment: Great! I have updated the file in github and I have made you a mension, Thanks.